# passing param between two page html

Tags: javascript

I would like to pass value to page 2(Dialog Page). but it shows me error

> Error: unrecognized expression

and if I remove  `id_travail="+Id+"'`  everything ok.

```
$('#header-left-container').prepend(results.rows.item(i).LibelleTypeTravail +"" +
"<br>" +
"<a href='#page_dialog?id_travail="+Id+"'  data-rel='dialog'>" +
"<img src='../js/images/add.png' id='img_go' class='upvote' name="+results.rows.item(i).IdTypeTravail+" ></a>" +
"<textarea rows='6'  cols='60' id='"+Id+"'   name='"+results.rows.item(i).LibelleTypeTravail+"'>" +
"</textarea><br><br>" ).trigger("create");
```

Comment: if i remove the "+" i'll have Error Parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"<a href='#page_dialog?id_travail='"+Id+"'  data-rel='dialog'>" +
```

This results in a invalid url hash: `"#page_dialog?id_travail=123"`
(Well, actually, any hash can be "valid", but in this case, you probably don't want `?id_travail=123` added to the hash, but to the url as parameter.)
You will need to pass url parameters before the url's hash (`#`):

```
"<a href='?id_travail='"+Id+"#page_dialog'  data-rel='dialog'>" +
```

Comment: the problem page dialog is contained dynamic will fill with the javascript code but it does not run the javascript code page of dialogue